# I want to use input variable which is initialized in 'if' condition to outside this condition

Tags: java, if-statement

I have some condition and in this condition I want to take input from user. But I also want to use this input outside this condition. I declare variable outside 'if' but I need its initialization in condition. So, is there anyway to use this outside in java or not?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: It's hard to tell, but it sounds like you just need to initialize the variable before the if condition, and then update the variable inside.

Answer (score 1):

You basically can 
initialize any primitive and overwrite it in your condition

Like an integer

```
int i = 0;
if (condition){
    i = userinput;
}
```

or a String

```
String i = "";
if (condition){
   i = userinput;
}
```

Comment: THANKS.... This helps me great. I am very confused from 3 days about this. And this is so simple.

Comment: Alternatively: `int i; if (condition) { i = userinput; } else { i = 0; }` (or `int i = condition ? userinput : 0;`). Assigning the variable once keeps it effectively final, meaning you can use it in lambdas, anonymous classes etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the variable outside of your if-statement with a default value. What value would your variable have, if you do not enter your if-statement but you want to read from it later on? This need to be declared. `null` is also possible. Or just declare your variable before the if-statement and initialize it inside the if-statement and also in an else branch of the same if-statement:

```
Object test = null;
if (condition == true) {
 test = new Object();
}
System.out.println(test);
```

or

```
Object test;
if (condition == true) {
 test = new Object();
} else {
  test = anotherValue;
}
System.out.println(test);
```

Comment: You needn't (and shouldn't) write `condition == true`: `condition` by itself is sufficient, shorter, and less error-prone.